# Does having more focused UpdatedPanels help versus just one big generic UpdatePanel around the entire page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Does having more focused UpdatedPanels, around fewer elements help versus just one big generic UpdatePanel around the entire page?
What is the advantage of doing such a thing?

Comment: The purpose of an UpdatePanel is to enable partial page rendering, hence if you use one UpdatePanel all must be re-rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having separate UpdatePanels will allow you to update isolated areas of a page, resulting in less downstream and potentially less server-side work.

For instance.  If you have a page with a `Label` surrounded by an `UpdatePanel`, along with a `GridView`surrounded by an `UpdatePanel`, you could add a `Timer` that does a post to the server every 5 seconds and updates the Label to the current DateTime.  When doing this, you would not have to re-bind your grid on the server side because the content of the grid is not involved in the downstream response.

The result would be:  bind the Label and Grid on the first request.  Refresh only Label on each Timer tick.

**EDIT:  Example added.**

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Bind Grid, only on first load
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();  //Set label
    UpdatePanel1.Update();  //Update only Label's update panel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the UpdatePanel only tells the engine which control needs to be redrawn; the [entire life cycle of the page still occurs](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/server-side-page-life-cycle-with-updatepanel-in-c/).

This is not to discount the benefits of redrawing lesser elements.